# GeoServer + Oracle multi-session

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

I have:

- GeoServer
- Oracle Spatial
- WMS

To communicate with Oracle, GeoServer uses the schema, username and password.

Is it possible to use multi-user to communicate with Oracle locator table or switch the Oracle?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Each GeoServer data store can have a different user if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If your GeoServer users match the Oracle ones, you can use an impersonation script, see here:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlsession.html#data-sqlsession